# tense (past or perfect) with the word "before" or "earlier"

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

Could you tell me if I am correct?

My friend has got new clothes and I say "why haven't you worn these before" (because I discover the new clothes in the present)

I have just seen a good movie, is it correct to say "why did not I see this movie before" (because the action is in the past)

If this is correct could you explain me more exactly

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples need a question mark at the end because they are questions.

> **Why haven't you worn these before?** is correct.

Similarly, the second example should be:

> **Why haven't I seen this movie before?**

If you refer to a specific time, you can also say:

> **Why didn't I see this movie when it first came out?**

Comment: Could you explain me the : similarly, the second example should be:

    Why haven't I seen this movie before?

Comment: It's the same as the first example. The first example is "worn these before" and the second is "seen this before." I'm not sure what you need explained.

Comment: I was not clear, I would like an explanation about the tense, here PP? (I do not understand what PP is used). Because there is not specific time implied?